# Uncaught exception on "ionic ions" (ionic 2 beta)

Tags: ionic2

`ionic list` should *List Ions, bower components, or addons in the project*
`ionic ions` should *List available ions to add to your project*
The first one runs correctly I suppose - as it throws no error but gives *ionic* as result. But when running *ions* task, I get an exception:

```
Error: Cannot find module './project'  
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>   (C:\Users\Notebook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\ions.js:2:20)
   at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
Cannot find module './project' (CLI v2.0.0-beta.22)   
Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
 Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
 Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
 Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.3
 Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.22
 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.12
 OS: Windows 7 SP1
 Node Version: v5.4.0
```

Technically the exception is right: there is no such file or folder in the project folder. Is this a beta bug, or am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Ionic2 CLI on Windows which is not yet supported according to this: http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-windows-support-in-ionic-2/#comment-2595217629

I would consider using docker with some basic [node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

Comment: Thank you. It looks that in CLI 2.0.0-beta.24 it is totally removed.